# VBA Error Handling: Unable to get the match property of the worksheet function class

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, match

Struggling with handling this error in my code: "Unable to get the match property of the worksheet function class"

I know that the error means there is no match found from the function. The problem is that I'm trying to tell the program to simply skip over a given loop iteration if a match is not found with this criteria. I placed the error handler right above the code that is likely to fail, but it pretty much ignores the error handler and gives me an error window anyway. Any ideas?

```
n = 2               
    On Error GoTo SkipRun
    Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n) <> ""
        l = Empty
        layercount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 11)

        startrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n)
        EndRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & n)
        searchRange = "A" & startrow & ":A" & EndRow


        l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("DLA", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0) + startrow - 1
```

Error occurs here ^

```
        Dim steps() As Variant
        ReDim steps(1, layercount)

                    a = 1
        Do While a <= layercount
            steps(1, a) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & l + a - 1)

            If a = 1 Then
                GoTo skiploop
            ElseIf a > 1 Then
                If steps(1, a) = steps(1, a - 1) Then steps(1, a) = 0
            End If
 skiploop:
                 a = a + 1
              Loop

SkipRun:
        n = n + 1
        Loop                'END OF MAIN LOOP
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you declare `searchRange`?

Comment: @BruceWayne searchRange is defined as` searchRange = "A" & startrow & ":A" & EndRow`.  both of these variables were also defined earlier in the code but for simplicity I figured I'd leave them out on here.

Comment: can you include all the code? It could be a few reasons as @YowE3k pointed out. Also what happens if you turn off the error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handling in VBA is a bit tricky. Basically, you are handling an error inside your loop, but you did not exit the procedure. You hit the error once, you handle it and you continue the loop - but you are still in the same sub - so the next error will raise regardless of the Error-handling mechanism that you had put in place..

To continue in your same procedure/loop after you caught and handled an error, you *need* to invoke in any way the `Resume` statement. After invoking `Resume`, your Error-Handling mechanism is again valid. In your case, you should do the following:

```
    On Error Goto ErrHandler
    Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n) <> ""
        .... ' your loop
NextN:
        n = n + 1
    Loop

    ...

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Resume NextN 'you need to call Resume, to continue your loop with valid error handling.

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `exit sub` and `end sub`?

Comment: @eob sure, `End Sub` marks the end of *the code* of the subroutine. `Exit Sub` is a way to exit from the sub and return to the caller at any point inside the subroutine.

Comment: What we do in the above code is to exit the sub before the `ErrHandler` if things go normally.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments above:

`startrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n)` <-- this is how to set a range, not to get the last row
`EndRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & n)` <-- this is how to set a range, not to get the last row

Anyway, your first `Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n) <> ""` has the same `n` for all of the lines below, which means you will get the same row number for `startrow` and `EndRow` , this is what you wanted ?? (this will also result that `searchRange` is a single cell in Column A)

What you need to do is "Catch" the good `Match` results, and ignore the cases there are not. You can do that with the following code using the `Application.Match` function :

```
' Match was unable to find a matching in range
If IsError(Application.Match("DLA", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0)) Then
    ' do nothing
Else ' <-- successful match
    l = Application.Match("DLA", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0) + startrow - 1
    ' rest of your Do While loop code here
End If
```

Or, you can do that also with 1 `If` criteria:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("DLA", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0)) Then
    l = Application.Match("DLA", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0) + startrow - 1
End If
```

**Note**: there is no need to use `l = Empty` in the lines above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to use `.row` here:

```
startrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n).row
EndRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & n).row
```

But it may be better to define it as a range:

```
Dim n As Long, startRow As Long, endRow As Long
Dim searchRange As Range
' n = whatever number
startRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n).Row
endRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & n).Row
Set searchRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & endRow)

l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("DLA", searchRange, 0) + startRow - 1
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP has the **value** of `startrow` in column B of Sheet1, and the **value** of `endrow` in column C  (i.e. they are trying to do an `Indirect`), otherwise both variables are going to be set to `n`.